# get wordpress posts grouped by month

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show all the Wordpress posts on a single page, and have the results showing like this example:

Posts for September (current month)

1- first post
2- second post
3- third post

Posts for NEXT MONTH

2- first post
2- second post
3- third post

I have accomplished this result to show all posts ordered by month, but i was unable to group them and make the posts show as a group for each month:

```
 <?php
$month = date('M');
$arrgs = array('orderby' => $month);
$myposts = get_posts($arrgs);
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="post-item">
    <div class="post-info">
        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="post-meta">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> Published in <strong><?php echo $month; ?></strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if there is another way, but I've had to do some direct queries to the database to acheive what you're looking for. This example has worked for me on many similar occasions.

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>               
 <ul>
  <?php
   $years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE  post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date ASC");

   foreach($years as $year) : ?>

    <h4><li><a href="<?php echo get_year_link($year ); ?> "><?php echo $year; ?></a>
     <ul>
      <?php $months = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date ASC");

      foreach($months as $month) : ?>

       <h4>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, $month); ?>"><?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );?></a>
         <ul>
          <?php  $theids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND MONTH(post_date)= '".$month."' AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date ASC");

           foreach ($theids as $theid): ?>

            <h4 style= font-style:italic;><li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?p=<?php echo $theid->ID; ?>"><?php echo $theid->post_title; ?></a></li></h4>  

           <?php endforeach; ?>

         </ul>                
        </li></h4>

       <?php endforeach;?>

      </ul>
     </li></h4>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Theres also [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/) plugin. It works great, but the level of customization mite not be on the same level. It certainly works though and would be the quickest and easiest solution to your situation.

Happy coding!

Comment: Downvoting for using multiple queries inside loops. That's just wrong.

Comment: @iKindred, care to provide a more adequate solution?

Answer (score 6):

@zillaofthegods here's my solution: I'd use only 1 query to get all the posts I want to display and then use PHP to do the heavy lifting. A good idea would be to ask for the year and month as extra columns since we are going to need those later.

```
global $wpdb; // Don't forget

$collection = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT YEAR(p.post_date) AS post_year, MONTH(p.post_date) AS post_month, p.*
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
  WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
", OBJECT );
```

Get the results and setup a chain of loops with the proper conditionals to get the data with the criteria you need. I haven't tried this but I think It explains my point:

```
// Loop once to grab the years
foreach ( $collection as $year ):

  // Loop for a second time to grab the months inside a year
  foreach ( $collection as $month ):

    // Continue unless years match
    if ( $month->post_year != $year ) continue;

    // Loop one more time to grab the posts inside the month, inside the year
    foreach ( $collection as $post ):

      // Continue unless months and years match
      if ( $post->post_year != $year || $post->post_month != $month ) continue;

      // You can use the posts data here

    endforeach;

  endforeach;

endforeach;
```

What's the benefit? You hit your DB once and everything else is done by PHP as part of the template rendering which can be easily cached.

Comment: upvoting for more efficient solution. thanks for taking up my request!